# Wolfram new products

Tags: wolfram-cloud, webmathematica, mathematica-online

Can someone elaborate on the products relating to Wolfram Cloud? They all seem the same. 
When I login to Wolfram Cloud there's:

- [Wolfram One](http://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-one/index.en.php?source=footer)
- [Wolfram Development Platform](http://www.wolfram.com/development-platform/?source=nav)
- [Wolfram Programming Lab](http://www.wolfram.com/programming-lab/index.en.html?footer=lang)
- [Wolfram Mathematica Online](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/)
- Create new Notebook

From what I can tell:

- Wolfram One is just Mathematica Online. I opened it and it just says "Create new Notebook".
- Programming Lab is just example notebooks that are used for practising Wolfram Language.
- I have no idea the difference between Wolfram One, Development Platform, Mathematica Online, and just opening a new notebook from the main login.

Comment: "The wider you spread it, the thinner it gets." - Gerald M. Weinberg (The Law of Raspberry Jam in "The Secrets of Consulting") :)

Comment: @gwr Good law,I agree with that totally. :)

Comment: So is thinner better or worse? There is so much overlap between old and new products (webMathematica vs W|A Widgets vs Deploy-able Notebooks) there's bound to be cannibalization. It seems like they're making new products whilst not retiring the old ones.

Comment: *Wolfram Two* is on the road. :)

Comment: I had a locally installed version of Wolfram One trail, but I have found no differences with Mathematica, nor are they explicitly stated on the product website...

Comment: At least closely related: [List of Mathematica related acronyms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104593/5478), maybe we should  edit the question there. Also, a partial answer on [wolfram community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1081329)

Comment: Another relevant Wolfram Community discussion of product overlap and product differentiation is <a href="http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1096129">here</a>.