# The relation between Wolfram development platform and Mathematica.

Tags: wolfram-cloud, mathematica-online

I have not used Mathematica before, but I know that there is a relation between Wolfram development platform and Mathematica. but I do not know this relation, could anyone clarify this for me or recommend a book for me to clarify basic things on Mathematica?

Comment: see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104593/5478

Comment: Have you followed links given you earlier? And links in those links? Have you search around? See for example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138366/5478. But first of all take a look at [asking guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help). Your question is too broad/unclear.

Comment: I am doing so now @Kuba